# Fixed width Div and expandable floated side by side?

Tags: css

Is it possible to have a fixed width div floated alongside a variable width div?

I would like to have a 80px image sit alongside a div that stretches to 100% of the remining width using dynamic content - the html would be a repeated version of below -

for example -

```
    <div class="mediaImg">
       <img src="#"/>
    </div>
    <div class="textArea">
    blah blah blah
    </div>
```

Thanks
Paul

Comment: I am not sure if understand. But from what I understand, you can just use some padding to achieve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write like

```
#divleft
{
    background-color:red;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    float:left;
}

#divright
{
    background-color:blue;   
    overflow:hidden;
    height:80px;
}
```

In this example of you give `padding & margin` to `#divright`. there is not effect in the layout structure.

check this  http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/u2sQD/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just apply float and an width on your fixed div:

```
div.fixed{
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/nvgBm/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I would put them inside a container type div with position:absolute then the two div's having relative positioning with float left.

```
<div class='container' width='100%'>
    <div class='imgDiv'>
         <img src='...'></img>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>

       ...content goes here

    </div>
</div>
```

Then the css...

```
    .container{
          position:absolute
          width:100%
          height:100%

            }
     .imgDiv{

        position:relative
        float:left
        width:80px
         }
      .content{
        position:relative
        float:left

        }
```

Comment: Can you please explain me why the absolute, why the 100%'s and why they have to be relative?